# what is the alternate of AddIdentity<DomainUser, DomainGroup>()..AddActiveDirectoryStores().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.1

I upgraded from ASP.NET Core 1.1 to 3.1

**

```
services.AddIdentity<DomainUser, DomainGroup>(options =>
            {
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/admin/account/login");
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            })
            .AddActiveDirectoryStores()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**

in this code i got this error:
Error   CS1061  'IdentityOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Cookies' and no accessible extension method 'Cookies' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Startup.cs 72  Active

is there any alternate code to done this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to reach the ApplicationCookie Options you have to call `ConfigureApplicationCookie`.
For your Code it would be:

```
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/admin/account/login");
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    });
```